# Consumin OData from Nav2015 via Javascript - Authentification fails

Tags: javascript, odata, microsoft-dynamics, navision

we try to connect to our OData from NAV2015
The Link and the username and the userpassword works fine if we just copy paste the url in ou rbrwser and manuall add the password and username.

We are abslutely new to javascript. 
See the code we found on the internet below:
(We di dnot change the functions yet sine we do not even manage to authentificate)
We would appriciate any help. 
We use the password not the webservice key

```
<head> 
    <title></title> 
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /> 
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
        var baseURL = 'OurURL'; 

        // Function to Invoke a NAV WebService 
        function InvokeNavWS(method, parameters, successFunc) { 
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                username: 'name',
                password: 'pw',
                url: baseURL + '?$format=json' + parameters,
                xhrFields: {
                    withCredentials: true
                },
                success: successFunc,
                error: HandleError
            }); 
        } 
        // Get the Company list 
        function SystemService_Companies() { 
            InvokeNavWS('Company', '', HandleResult_Companies); 
        } 

        // Handle the results from the Company list
        function HandleResult_Companies(result) {
            var companies = result.value;
            var companyText = "";
            for (var i = 0; i < companies.length; i++) { 
                companyText += companies[i].Name + '<br>'; 
            } 
            $('#companies').html(companyText);
        }

        // Get details for a specific Customer
        function CustomerPage_Read(no) { 
            InvokeNavWS('CustomerList', '&$filter=No eq \'' + no + '\'', HandleResult_Customer); 
        } 

        // Handle the results from the Customer call
        function HandleResult_Customer(result) {
            $('#cust10000').html('Name of Customer 10000: ' + 
                    result.value[0].Name + '<br>'); 
        }

        // Get details for multiple Customer
        function CustomerPage_ReadMultiple(filters) { 
            InvokeNavWS('CustomerList', filters, HandleResult_MultipleCustomer); 
        } 

        // Handle the results from the Customer call
        function HandleResult_MultipleCustomer(result) {
            var Customers = result.value;
            var customersText = "Customers in ES served by ROT or BLAU warehouse:<br>";
            for (i = 0; i < Customers.length; i++) {
                customersText += Customers[i].Name + ', Contact ' + Customers[i].Contact + '<br>';
            }
            $('#custList').html(customersText);
        }

        function HandleError(err) {
            console.log(err);
        }

    </script> 
</head>  
<body> 
    <div id="companies">
        <a href="#">get Companies</a>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div id="cust10000">
        <a href="#">get Customer 10000</a>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div id="custList">
        <a href="#">get Customers in ES served by ROT or BLAU warehouse</a>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript"> 
        $("#companies a").click(function () { SystemService_Companies(); }); 
        $("#cust10000 a").click(function () { CustomerPage_Read(10000); });
        $("#custList a").click(function () { CustomerPage_ReadMultiple("&$filter=Country_Region_Code eq 'ES' and (Location_Code eq 'ROT' or Location_Code eq 'BLAU')"); });
    </script> 
</body>
```

Comment: Please provide the exact GET request you are using in your browser. so I can compare.

Comment: Do you mean the exact url we use? We are using the code as it is atm